# Век живи, век учись

Tags: c++builder

Может быть, это полезно некоторым, вроде меня. Читал Кормена "Алгоритмы..." и неожиданно для себя обнаружил, что освобождение от отладки (Project->Options->Compiler->Release) увеличивает скорость исполнения по крайней мере в 4 раза.
Программа "Сортировка вставкой" на 32000 случайных целых в диапазоне величин 31000 - 32000 выполнена с отладкой за 1.6 с, а без оной за 0.36 с. С чем себя и поздравляю!

Comment: век живи, век учись - это точно

Comment: ну в продакшн никто отладку и не включает. это только при разработке она требуется где скорость не так важна.

Comment: Разве не очевидно что отладка замедляет скорость работы проги?

Как по мне это очевидно

Comment: Где вопрос? Кто видел здесь вопрос!?

Answer (score 4):

Ясное дело. Включение отладки добавляет дополнительный код в вашу программу, некоторые дополнительные проверки. Кроме того, оптимизация кода минимальная, чтобы сделать саму отладку возможной иначе соответствие между машинным кодом и исходным кодом станет не однозначным.